# Git: How to reattach a branch to its trunk?

Tags: git

I'd like to port a solution with several branches off a master branch from TFS to Git.  I've tried using Git-Tfs to port the solution and maintain the branch relationships, but the best I can do without the tool erroring out is to get a copy of the entire containing folder with separate subfolders for each of the branches - the branch relationships are not maintained.  The folder structure looks like this... the child folders contain the respective solution files and content:

```
MyProject
  --Main 
  --Features
    --FeatureBranch1
    --FeatureBranch2
```

Also, commits seem to be tracked only at the `MyProject` level, nothing at the subfolder level.  I know the changeset number where each of the branches occurred, but I'm not sure how to use that information, if it's even applicable.

I need to reassociate each of the branches with the master but can't figure out how (I'm a Git newbie).  I don't care that much about the history - I just have to be able to merge the branches back into the trunk at some point.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't get the tooling to work (I'm not that familiar with TFS so I can't speak to any available tools, sorry), you can do it manually without preserving history. I've worked on something similar going from Subversion to Git, which had the similar issue of handling branches as subdirectories.

1. Export your master-equivalent branch (Main I assume?)
2. `git init`, add all, commit
3. `git checkout -b <branchname>` for the first branch to add
4. Delete all the working copy files, but *not* the `.git` directory
5. Export the equivalent branch from TFS and copy the files into your working copy
6. `git add --all` - this will recognize changes, additions, and deletions
7. Commit
8. Check out master again
9. Repeat from step 3 for the next branch, until all branches are done
10. `git push --all` to push all branches to your upstream

This will maintain the branch ancestry, but not the change history. This was fairly easy to script out for SVN, presumably also pretty easy to script out for TFS.

Comment: Hot dang, that seems to have worked.  Thank you *so* much!